# How many passes are enough with memtest (6 years later)

Tags: memory, memory-error

Originally, this question was asked here:
[How many passes are enough with Memtest?](https://superuser.com/questions/547822/how-many-passes-are-enough-with-memtest)

The question is from 2013, and the answers are from 2013.

I am bringing it up again because it has been 6 years or more since it was asked, and that is an eternity in computer hardware years.

Fast forward to today. I am running memtest on my machine with 32gb ram.  Gone are the days of catching errors in the first few seconds, unless something is REALLY wrong. A single pass takes a very long time to get to 100%.

I let my system run overnight and it caught 2 errors.  It passed 6 times, failed 2.  Do you think these are true errors or, is it more like its an acceptable amount of failure?

Edit: I ran this test because I was getting bluescreen errors that may be driver related, but i'm testing each part independently.

Edit2: Placed bounty on the old question because I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: "I am bringing it up again because it has been 6 years or more since it was asked" --> the solution is to place a bounty on the old question, not ask the same question again. You don't want people doing a web search to find duplicate posts which might then be equally outdated…

Comment: There is no acceptable amount of failure. Study well the Memtest results for the tests that failed, whether they are addressing failures relating to motherboard/CPU or only to RAM.

Comment: Bounty placed. Thank you @slhck ... even though I only have 106 on superuser.  All my points are on stackoverflow.

Comment: You'll get there :) Thanks for considering to place a bounty.