# BSOD several errors W10

Tags: bsod, memory-management

i am getting several erros from MEMORY_MANAGEMENT and SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION since i build this computer. I already tried all the normal procedures like scan virús, Chkdsk, SFC and reinstalled windows. Nothing resolved my problem.
Used memtest86 and didnt find any erros.

Atached some minidmp files

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gws5yynvwqxjmur/041419-8687-01.dmp?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pjyg58z72dhz678/041419-8906-01.dmp?dl=0

[Memory Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOYhQ.png)

[System Service Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDSAy.png)

If any one can help me solve this headach i will really appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The crash happens in Windows, not in a driver. Run memtest86 again - see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1413045/8672). In the worse case, reinstall Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @harrymc. I already reinstalled windows and the problem persists. For the memtest86, i will follow the recomended 8passes through the night and ill let you know if it found any errors. Thanks