# Non-system-disk error on Windows 7/10 restart

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have a very specific error with an HP Elitebook 8540w notebook into which I have recently upgraded the hard drive, from a Crucial 500GB drive to a Samsung 1TB SSD.

Via booting to a Ubuntu 14 live CD and the GParted partition manager I was able to clone all partitions from the old drive to the new, including a Linux/Windows dual boot.

The clone was unable to duplicate all the aspects of the boot process, with GRUB first and Windows boot manager second. Firstly I was able to use the live CD again and boot-repair the GRUB configuration. Secondly the Windows CD to repair the Windows boot loader. I am able to boot into either Linux or Windows, everything is exactly as it was and applications work.

Now when I an in Windows and initiate a 'restart', the computer will fail to find the hard drive as it reboots, issuing a 'non-system disk or disk error'. A hard reset of the machine corrects the issue and the disk is found fine, showing the GRUB menu.

Restarting from Linux (Ubuntu 16 LTS) does not cause the error, only Windows, and only a soft restart. I have run the BIOS disk checker and memory checker with no errors, re-seated the drive, nothing changes the behaviour.

The reason for the drive upgrade was that occasionally in Windows the system disk would be lost to access and the system would blue-screen shortly after, with no logged errors since it couldn't save them to disk. I presumed the 4 year old SSD that had a hard life was giving up, now I'm not so sure.

Any ideas?

BIOS version: F60 Rev. A 11/11/2015

**Update 06/04/2020:**

I have since updated to Windows 10 and the issue has not changed. The system is now significantly less stable and this issue may or may not be contributing to that instability.

**Update 06/04/2020 #2:**

Stability issues seem to have been resolved, and were centred around, RAM that was failing. This fix has not influenced the main issue this question is formed around.

See below that Fast start is not available, hibernate has been disabled in these machines (32GB RAM, SSD, a lot of wear)

[image: Windows power management dialog]

**Update 08/04/2020: Sleep function fails**

A symptom that could be related is a failure to sleep. Upon trying to sleep the machine the machine did what it sometimes does when it crashes hard. There are no messages of interest in the Event Viewer, and as it is restarting, the speakers release a couple of seconds chaotic popping and rattling sounds. I've assumed the sound device just gets in a funny state and starts amplifying a load of random data/switching of devices while the restart happens.

**Update 09/04/2020:**

Result of `powercfg -energy` is posted on pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/ez0Y7MnM), expiring in 14 days.

Partition layout on drive. I believe these were created using GParted within Linux, and data cloned onto the drives from the host drive having an identical partition layout. The original SSD was 500 GB so all partitions were generally smaller. The original layout started as a pure Windows installation with a post-installation of Ubuntu Linux which modified the partition layout and added a GRUB boot menu:

[image: Partition Layout]

System Reserved:

- F:
- List item
- Primary partition
- 350 MB
- Windows boot/recovery (?)
- NTFS

Windows7

- C:
- Primary partition
- 150 GB
- Windows OS drive
- NTFS

Unnamed partition

- /swp
- Primary partition
- 32 GB
- Linux swap drive
- SWAP

Unnamed partition

- /
- Primary partition
- 150 GB
- Linux OS drive
- EXT4

Unnamed partition

- Extended partition
- Unnamed drive

  - I:
  - Logical drive
  - 599.17 GB
  - Windows/Linux shared storage
  - NTFS

Comment: Do you have a fast boot enabled or anything like that in your Control Panel? This causes Windows to perform a hybrid shutdown similar to hibernate, so the filesystem would be in an inconsistent condition, which possibly could be causing it (sometimes they’re correlated, sometimes they’re not, depends on the machine)

Comment: @VarunNarravula Where would I find settings such as that?

Comment: You can find that in your Control Panel. Go to Control Panel and search up Power settings, then click on “change what the power buttons do” and then hibernate and fast boot should come up. Disable both if available; you need admin privileges. There is also a setting in the BIOS for fast boot usually. Disable that also if applicable.

Comment: @VarunNarravula Such feature doesn't exist in Windows 7. It started with Windows 8. And it's called "Fast Startup". "Fast boot" is a UEFI feature, not Windows.

Comment: @VarunNarravula I have checked the BIOS and cannot see any reference to fast boot or the like.

Comment: Is there any option in BIOS/UEFI to set the disk I/O mode? It may be named as SATA Mode options AHCI/IDE? If yes, did you try changing from AHCI to IDE or vice versa? However, this might make your Windows 10 further unstable. Is the BIOS updated to the latest version?

Comment: I will try this now. Can I assume IDE mode will be significantly slower? Result switching from AHCI to IDE is a blue screen on boot: `INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE`. This is after the windows logo and the spinning dots appear for a period. On the blue screen reboot however the behaviour is no longer apparent. A hint at the problem?

Comment: IDE mode will be a bit slower than SATA.  I had exact same issue with my Asus laptop. On restart of Windows 10 it would fail to find the HDD. Windows locks to the SATA mode in BIOS. There’s a registry change to prevent if BSOD occurs but I cannot comment on it. I set SATA mode to IDE in BIOS (I did not get BSOD but Windows 10 was unstable and sometimes would enter into boot repair) and then later I did a clean install of Windows 10 with IDE mode. Thereafter it always worked for both cold boot & soft boot. May or may not be related but this is what worked in my case.

Comment: Fast Startup should be disabled for dual boot. See [How to Turn On or Off Fast Startup in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html). It's not a feature of the BIOS.

Comment: I can assure that Fast startup is not enabled for this machine.

Comment: I suggest running [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for as many passes as possible but at least two ([link](https://superuser.com/a/1413045/8672)).

Comment: @harrymc I left MemTest86 5.01 running all night, no errors were found there.

Comment: Good, the motherboard is perhaps in good shape. A sleep problem can be analyzed by running [powercfg -energy](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html) to a file. Posting the file somewhere for us might help.

Comment: How do you specifically initiate a restart?

Comment: For the sleep I have the power button mapped to sleep mode. Restart is usually in any form, but for example Windows>Power>Restart would do. @harrymc the powercfg -energy is done and attached to the question.

Comment: Do you have crashes (`.dmp`) in `C:\Windows\Minidump`? If yes, please post some. If not, ensure that Windows is configured correctly to [Create Dump Files on BSOD](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5560-configure-windows-10-create-minidump-bsod.html).

Comment: @JCollins Do not change from AHCI to IDE, as your PC's BIOS needs to be set to AHCI.  There's only four things that come to mind that could cause this: Hardware issue _(which you appear to have ruled out)_, partition configuration issue _(is Windows not seeing the HDD or the `C:` partition, as your usage of "drive" seems to imply the latter, and if it is the latter, it could be a result of managing/cloning Windows partitions from Linux, rather than through the native way Windows has always supported: `ImageX` in Windows <=7 or `DISM` in Windows >=8)_, or an OEM driver/BIOS issue. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _Cont'd..._  While it is possible to upgrade Windows 7 or 8 to Windows 10, it's never recommended due to the OEM driver incompatibility between Windows <=8 & Win10 [result: instability]. Easiest way to rule out partition configuration issue is to do a clean install of Win10, disconnecting from the internet during the install, installing the CPU chipset & IMEI driver immediately upon exiting OOBE and **before installing _any_ other drivers, software, or Windows Updates**.  _(CPU drivers must be installed first and are the only drivers incapable of being installed via Windows Updates in Win10.)_

Comment: Clearing the drive and doing a fresh install is in this circumstance the nuclear option for several reasons, one being risking a very expensive nodelocked piece of software. I have added information to the question about the partition layout. Perhaps there is a tool that can analyse partition layouts for compatibility with Windows and its sleep/restart/hibernate routines?

Comment: Everything hardware looks correct. An upgrade sometimes is not complete. Perhaps you should in addition do a [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) to itself with the latest version.

Comment: @harrymc I have in fact already done the in-place upgrade and it had no influence on the issue.

Comment: No more ideas. You might need to accept this problem as is.