# Please help me i dont know solution for this

Tags: windows-8.1

I have **big problem** its **new clean installation of Windows 8.1** and show me some problems like this **Your pc ran into some problem** anyone know solution for this . I am trying to fix this for 2 weeks i renistall windows and after 3 days again same problem
here log file from Windows/Minidump
https://www.sendspace.com/file/tqo62t
Tell me if you needs more logs file

Comment: Have you tried booting into safe mode and reviewing the logs?

Comment: Yes but i dont know what it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analysis of the `.dmp` file show a MEMORY_MANAGEMENT error.
The likely cause of the problem is a bad RAM stick.
Other reasons for such crashes exist but are much more troublesome to identify.

If you have recently installed new RAM, let us know exactly which type and also
the details for your computer.

I would suggest running
[MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/)
for as many passes and as many hours as you can, but for at least two passes.
The results can identify a memory problem and even CPU and motherboard problems.
([link](https://superuser.com/a/1413045/8672))

If your RAM includes multiple sticks, you could test the computer with only
one RAM stick in the computer at a time, in order to identify a bad stick.

Comment: Ok i will try MemTest86

Comment: My second ram is dead :'(

Comment: To replace it, make sure that the new stick is identical to the one that works, or at least has exactly the same properties.

Comment: Ok thank you @harrymc