# Can RAM errors disapper when reseating them?

Tags: memory

I‘ve got a new computer and over time got more and more issues (been 4 weeks now). CPU (Intel I7-11700) was overheating and thermal throttling to stay below 100 degrees.

Now I fixed this issue by removing a sticker from the cooler (forgot to remove it) but I still had issues with crashes.

I then ran MemTest86 which reported 10 errors on the first run.

I then tested all rams individually and also each slow without any errors.

I now added all ram sticks again and the test shows again no errors.

Is it possible that a ram can be detected but show some errors when it is not 100% fitted correctly or shouldn‘t it be detected at all? I‘m worried that because of the termal issues the ram or mainboard or cpu got damaged but afer I researed all rams, I don‘t see anymore issues.

Answer (score 3):

If they are not seated correctly, or you get in dust or oil, then yes reseating them could remove that issue.

One thing to remember is that memtest and similar can never guarantee that memory is free from errors, it only tells you how likely it is to occur.

I would let it run at least over night to reduce the likelihood of false negative. I would then run tests in OS that excersises both CPU, GPU, and memory if possible.

Comment: Related: [How many passes are enough with Memtest?](https://superuser.com/q/547822/432690)